# Decompress gzip response in salesforce apex

Tags: rest, salesforce, integration, apex, compression

Anybody worked on the httpresponse gzip decompression?
Client is sending the response in compression format and we need to decompress it in salesforce.

Request:
We have added `Accept-Encoding : deflate` in the request and `setcompressed` to true.

We are getting response like below:

> 11:13:50:810 USER_DEBUG
>   [9]|DEBUG|response::::x��Os�8�=�U��M�@��zI�L'E�H���,:`    i!�"�
>   ����|�Yd�{��,\K@�oU�

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code?